# Update product variations prices in Woocommerce with WPDB query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, post-meta

I am using WordPress 4.7.4 and WooCommerce 3.0.5.

I updated `_sale_price`,  `_price`, `_regular_price` using `meta_id` with code below:

```
   $meta_tbl = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
   foreach ($_POST['loop'] as $loop_k => $loop_v) {
        $wpdb->update(
            $meta_tbl,
                array( 'meta_value' => $loop_v['price'] ),
                array( 'meta_id' => $loop_v['price_meta_id'] ),
                array( '%d' )
            );
        $wpdb->update(
            $meta_tbl,
                array( 'meta_value' => $loop_v['regular_price'] ),
                array( 'meta_id' => $loop_v['regular_price_meta_id'] ),
                array( '%d' )
            );
        $wpdb->update(
            $meta_tbl,
                array( 'meta_value' => $loop_v['sale_price'] ),
                array( 'meta_id' => $loop_v['sale_price_meta_id'] ),
                array( '%d' )
            );
  }
```

But still the shop page is displaying the old price of products! How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by adding this line after your code.

```
wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id );
```

// $post_id replace with product ID

Comment: Didnt workd for me. Still shows the wrong price everywhere, except in the cart.

Comment: @KarlJohanVallner Are you using any price adjustment plugins? Also try deleting transient cache under WooCoommerce -> Status -> Tools

Comment: No plugins. For some odd reason, clearing cache doesnt do anything either. But when I manually update the price under "Products", it works out swell.