# How to trigger "Update" button programmatically - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Script that uploads/updates products into my WooCommerce website programmatically from of a JSON file.

Script is used to update *product variations* as well.

I am using Wordpress's built-in functions to insert/update POSTS or POSTS_METAS

Everything is working perfectly, I can see variant prices are being updated fine.

But only thing that is not working is the price range displayed under title of a product
[image]

This range is actually the

```
lowest price of a variant - highest price of a variant
```

It only gets updated if I press the blue colored "`UPDATE`" button from admin area.

I also tried doing(after inserting/updating all variants)

```
wp_update_post(array(
    'ID'    =>  $post_id,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish'
    ));
```

But had no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sale price programmatically to product variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547590/add-sale-price-programmatically-to-product-variations)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out those prices are also cached in transient `wp_options` table.

So, I've find solution that worked for me:

```
wc_delete_product_transients($post_id);
```